# Can I run the webapps independently from the browser?

Tags: webapps

I was wondering if it is possible to run a webapp without it opening the browser.

For example i have pinned the facebook webapp to my launcher, but when i click on it, it opens the browser and starts the integration with facebook.
I just want it to start the integration and not open www.facebook.com in my browser.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a web application needs to run inside the web browser.

That being said there's still some things Ubuntu's webapps integration code could do that it's not doing yet, like running the application without all the browser's UI to make the web application feel more native, but that work is not complete yet.